# Как сделать несколько уровневый chart в chart.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

Всем привет, скажите как можно создать несколько уровневый chart pie как на скрине?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня получилось сделать только такой, ниже прикладываю параметры что я передаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
          chartOptions: {
            hoverBorderWidth: 20
          },
          chartData: {
            hoverBackgroundColor: "red",
            hoverBorderWidth: 10,
            labels: ["Green", "Red", "Blue"],
            datasets: [
              {
                label: "Data One",
                backgroundColor: ["#41B883", "#E46651", "#00D8FF"],
                data: [90, 10, 5]
              }
            ]
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

Этот сайт ответит на ваш вопрос [тыц](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/pie.html) просто добавьте ещё один `dataset`

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)